# How do i iterate in a for loop for python while using a list of tuples and trying to print out the data for a specific part?

Tags: python, loops, tuples

So my programs goal is to distribute 2 items of different value to each person.

The program receives a number and the list of tuples. The number is all the people after me when I pick my first item.

The order for picking is the first person picks one all the way to the last then the last picks again then backwards all the way to the first.

Now what I'm struggling with is understanding how to use for loops to go through these tuples and print out what 2 items I chose. To figure out how many people are actually trying to get items is by taking all the available items and dividing by 2. I am also confused by that

ex input:

```
(0, [('pizza', 12), ('chicken', 10),] )
```

So with this example the program should be printing out: "pizza:12 chicken:10"

Answer (score 0):

To make sure I got the question correctly:

- There are n items and n/2 people
- The first person in the list gets the best (highest value) and the worst (lowest value) item. The second person gets the second-best item and second-worst, etc.
- There are k people behind you in the list, so you are in position n/2-k
- You want to know which two items of the list you get

If you just want to know the two items *you* get, you don't need a loop. You can just sort the items by value, compute the two indexes in the list that will fall to you. They would be n/2 - k - 1 (caution, indices are zero-based!), and n/2 + k:

```
def which_items_do_i_get(people_after_me, items):
    # Get items sorted by value
    sorted_items = sorted(items, key=lambda x: -x[1])
    # Determine number of people
    number_of_people = len(items) // 2
    assert len(items) % 2 == 0  # Must be an even number of items
    assert people_after_me < number_of_people  # Need more items
    # Determine first and second item
    first_item = sorted_items[number_of_people - people_after_me - 1]
    second_item = sorted_items[number_of_people + people_after_me] 
    # Print them out
    for item_name, item_value in first_item, second_item:
        print '%s: %d' % (item_name, item_value)
```

Comment: Yes and the goal is to pick obviously the best items so you have to remove the ones that the previous people would have taken.

Comment: Oh I see. Well then just sort the items by value before. Updated the solution.